# Getting metadata from Views from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-metadata

Is there a way to get from SQL Server metadata information about the dependencies of a view, in which manner are linked together (inner join, left join, right join) and the join's keys? (that_table.Id = my_table.That_tableId  AND X.Id = Z.XId) ?

I've found:

SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referencing_id = object_id('dbo.v_myView')

but is very far from my goal.

edit:
For example: this is the View:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
AS
  SELECT A.NAME
         B.AGE
         C.SURNAME
  FROM TABLE1 A 
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
  ON A.ID1 = B.Table1_key1 AND A.ID2 = B.Table1_Key2
  LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C
     ON C.ID = A.Table3Id
```

this is the expected result from the query i'm looking for

| id | object_name | dependecies | RefParent | typeOfJoin | keys |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MyView | table1 | null | null | null |
| 2 | MyView | table2 | 1 | inner join | A.ID1 = B.Table1_key1 AND A.ID2 = B.Table1_Key2 |
| 3 | MyView | table3 | 1 | left join | C.ID = A.Table3Id |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with `dependency of a view` ?

Comment: If you execute the query i posted, you should see a column "referenced_entity_name". In that column from my understanding, you are getting the tables used in the select to compose the result. So in my understanding, the tables used in the select are  dependencies of a view

Comment: Can you post an example of a view and what exact you whish to see as result

Comment: I am not sure this will be so easy, in the view you can join on whatever columns you want, even columns that are not in a foreign key, and I believe the system tables only list relations that are defined in foreign keys, primary keys and indexes.

Comment: I guess all you can do is retrieve the code of the view from  `select table_name, view_definition from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where table_name = 'dbo.v_myView'` and then parse it to figure out all the joins that where made there

Comment: I think you would need an SQL parser/exer for this. There is no information in the system view that shows the info you want

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

is probably what you're looking for?

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE might also help.

Comment: The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE` shows columns that are used as foreign key or primary key, not columns that are used in code of a view. So I am afraid to is useless for the OP. In a view you can write joins on any table and any column you want, none of those will end up in this table or any other table

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE shows all of the columns in the view, tables used, schema - which is why it "might help"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/view-column-usage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15